# Open a popup (e.g. native browser) from a Teams desktop client app tab

Tags: microsoft-teams

Is there any way to pop open a browser window from a Teams app tab (desktop client)?

I came across the following [link](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-library-js/issues/171) and from my interpretation of the reply it seems it's not possible.

Quoted from link for reference:

> Unfortunately it’s not possible to use window.open in Teams tabs. Because we block opening of new windows to arbitrary sites within our Teams Desktop Client (for security reasons) you need to always use microsoftTeams.authentication.authenticate (if you want a popup window) or microsoftTeams.tasks.startTask (if you want an iframe-based dialog) to open a secondary app view.

It's not very clear to me what the **microsoftTeams.authentication.authenticate** reference above is suggesting.

Alternatively, if not a browser window, can we attempt to open another app installed on the device (e.g. Excel)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you just wanting to launch a new browser entirely? If so, a regular anchor tag, with a target attribute (e.g. ...), will work fine (I'm doing this in a tab myself, and it's working without problem).

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a [TaskModule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/what-are-task-modules) to open a custom HTML/ Javascript or an iframe based widget inside a popup from within your Teams tab.

microsoftTeams.authentication.authenticate() will let you Authenticate the user against you tab. You can find the docs for this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-tab-aad).

Comment: if exist solution to have non modal dialog?

Answer (score 0):

There is the option to use authentication.authenticate with external = false, this method creates a pop up to a url of your choosing

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).